# VB .NET O365 EWS Shared Mailbox showing no folders

Tags: vb.net, office365, exchangewebservices

I have the following code, which functioned perfectly until a recent migration to O365:

```
        Dim ExServ As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1) With {
     .Credentials = New WebCredentials("username@mydomain.com", "password"),
    .Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx")
        }

    Dim Mailbox As New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "sharedmailbox@mydomain.co.uk")

    Dim Emails = ExServ.FindItems(Mailbox, New ItemView(10000))

    Dim InboxFolder As Folder = Folder.Bind(ExServ, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)
    InboxFolder.Load()

    Dim f As New FolderView(50)

    Dim g As FindFoldersResults = InboxFolder.FindFolders(f)
```

Now, the problem I have is that the call to FindFolders shows a count of zero folders found, when this mailbox has a couple of dozen folders inside it...

I have tried as an admin user to eliminate permissions, and the code can see emails in the Inbox folder fine. As I say, this all worked perfectly until we migrated to 365 recently.

Anyone seen this before or have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things i can see firstly

```
  Dim Emails = ExServ.FindItems(Mailbox, New ItemView(10000))
```

Because of paging the throttling this would only ever return 1000 items and you would need to page your request to get further items.

You also have

```
 Dim Mailbox As New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "sharedmailbox@mydomain.co.uk")
```

Which you use in your findItems request however you don't use it in the FolderBind Request that you subsequently use to search for folders. This means the FindFolder request would run against the mailbox of security credentials your using rather then "sharedmailbox@mydomain.co.uk" which your finditems request ran against. If you want the Folder Search to run against the SharedMailbox you would need

```
Dim InboxFolder As Folder = Folder.Bind(ExServ, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,"sharedmailbox@mydomain.co.uk")
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, and specifically where it relates to linking the Folder.Bind request to a specific mailbox, but you can't send a FolderId object as the third parameter... Trying to find an alternative. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry the name of the variable confused me a little i though you where using the Mailbox Class. But you can pass either a String for the Email or a Mailbox Class as an overload for that method (really intellisense you tell you this)